# No recibo respuestas del cmd a la hora de ejecutar mi api de puppeteer

Tags: javascript, scraping, puppeteer, scrap

Hace poco comence en el mundo del web scraping con la libreria/herramienta de puppeteer. Me encargaron realizar una api que recopile la informacion principal de los pokemon de la pokedex (Nombre, id de la pokedex, tipos)de la pagina https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/ Hasta ahi todo bien, este es el codigo que me resulto al final...

```js
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');
(async() =>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 926 });
    await page.goto('https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/');

    let datospokemon = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let nombrepokemon = [];
        let pokenombre = document.querySelectorAll('h5');

        pokenombre.forEach((pokeelement) => {
            let pokenombrecito = [];
            try {
                pokenombrecito.nombre = pokeelement.querySelector('h5').innerText;
                pokenombrecito.id=pokeelement.querySelector('p.id').innerText;
                pokenombrecito.tipos=pokeelement.querySelector('div.abilities').innerText;
            }
            catch (exception){

            };
            nombrepokemon.push(pokenombrecito);
        });
        return nombrepokemon;
    })
    console.dir(datospokemon);
})();
```

Pero a la hora de ejecutarlo desde el cmd de windows con node index3.js(que es el nombre del javascript que le asigne) no recibe respuesta alguna del cmd y no se despliega ningun tipo de informacion(anexo el texto que aparece):

```js
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1139]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\susan>node index3.js
[]
```

Si me pudiesen ayudar y corregir  este problemita se los agradeceria mucho ya que soy nuevo con este tema y se me dificulta un poco.
Un abrazo!

---

No entiendo a que te refieres , he tratado de acoplarlo con lo que me has dado pero nada mira

```js
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');
(async() =>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 926 });
    await page.goto('https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/');

    let datospokemon = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let nombrepokemon = [];
        let pokenombre = document.querySelectorAll('section.pokedex-results > ul > li');

        pokenombre.forEach((pokeelement) => {
            let pokenombrecito = [];
            let pokes = [];
            let  poke = document.querySelectorAll("section.pokedex-results > ul > li");
            for(let unpoke of pokes){
                pokenombrecito.nombre = unBicho.querySelector('h5').innerText;
                pokenombrecito.id = unBicho.querySelector('p.id').innerText;
            }
            nombrepokemon.push(pokenombrecito.innerText);
        });
        return nombrepokemon;
    })
    console.log(datospokemon);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirá esta parte:

```
let pokenombre = document.querySelectorAll('h5');

pokenombre.forEach((pokeelement) => {
    // ...
    x = pokeelement.querySelector('p.id').innerText;
    // ...
}
```

Estás haciendo esto:

1. Seleccionando todos los `<h5>`, y para cada uno
2. buscás los elementos hijos que sean ..... (!!!)

**Error** me imagino que el `<h5>` sólo tiene el nombre, y no tiene hijos con la información que estás buscando. Deberías posicionarte en un elemento padre que sea común a toda la info que estás buscando (o en su defecto desde document).

> Recién entré a esa página, con lo mucho que odio los Pokemones... quizás te interese algo como:
>
> ```
>  let bichos = document.querySelectorAll("section.pokedex-results > ul > li");
>  for (let unBicho of bichos) {
>      pokenombrecito.nombre = unBicho.querySelector('h5').innerText;
>      pokenombrecito.id = unBicho.querySelector('p.id').innerText;
>      //  ....etc
>      // acá agregarías al array donde estás juntando toda la info
>  }
> ```

---

---

---

Para que se entienda mejor, así se vería dentro de tu código

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');
(async() =>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 926 });
    await page.goto('https://www.pokemon.com/us/pokedex/');

    let datospokemon = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let nombrepokemon = [];
        let pokenombre = document.querySelectorAll('section.pokedex-results > ul > li');

        pokenombre.forEach((pokeelement) => {

            // esta es la parte editada -->

            let pokenombrecito = {};
            pokenombrecito.nombre = pokeelement.querySelector('h5').innerText;
            pokenombrecito.id = pokeelement.querySelector('p.id').innerText;
            pokenombrecito.tipos = pokeelement.querySelector('div.abilities').innerText;

            nombrepokemon.push(pokenombrecito);

            // <-- hasta acá la parte editada

        });
        return nombrepokemon;
    })
    console.log(datospokemon);
    await browser.close();
})();
```